# Why won't printf return # of spaces text?

Tags: c

Not sure why the following code does not return the number of spaces when providing a sentence for getchar(). I want the program to return one line of text that records the number of spaces in a given sentence.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
 int blarp, space;
 space = 0;

 printf("give me input\n");

 while((blarp = getchar()) != EOF)
 {
  if(blarp == ' ')
  {
   space++;
  }
 }

 printf("there are %d spaces", space);
}
```

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: What is your input?  How do you close `stdin`?

Comment: @haris I get no output--the program is still running, but it seems to never get to the printf statement outside of the while loop.

Comment: @chux i will input something small like, "this is some input". Still a beginner, not sure if i know how i close stdin. Google is telling me it's for input-- is this a header file i need to include?

Comment: See my answer I have tested the code and it works. You have to use suitable **sentinel** value.

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar just ran this code and got the same result as before. I then tried it adding an '!' to the end of the input text--this produces the right output, but only if the input text ends with an '!'.  I am wondering now if there is something misleading about using EOF in the while loop?

Comment: Did you add **'!'** at the end of the input? Can you show what command you use to run the code? Are you giving input from keyboard?

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar I am giving input from the keyboard. Using the command line, compiling "cc file.c", executing "./a.out".

Comment: just type whatever input you want, then add a **!** as the last character and hit enter.

Comment: `EOF` stands for **End Of File** and it is used when reading from a file. But since, you are using a keyboard you will have to specify a key as **sentinel** you can change **'!'** to whatever key you wish in the code, because there has to be some way to stop it. You can change it to **'\n'** in the code; by doing this it will stop as soon as you hit enter.

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar the '!' gives the right answer--thank you! I am thinking that EOF might not be working the way I imagined it would; it seems to be preventing the loop from exit.

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar thank you for explaining, this cleared up all my confusion!

Comment: I guess then you should mark my answer as **Accepted** :)

Comment: Actually you can send EOF as input. if you are working with Windows hit Ctrl+Z and in Linux Ctrl+D. It is treated as EOF

Comment: Pooya, no, you can't "send EOF".  You can close the input stream, which will cause getchar to return EOF.  ctrl-D just closes the input stream.  Perhaps this is semantics, but "send EOF" implies a sentinel character, which does not exist.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks I will add that info to the answer as well.

Comment: Maybe the author meant new line (Enter key) instead of EOF?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem is with the `EOF` you used in the stopping condition of `while` it means **End Of File** and is used when reading from a file. As notified by Pooya it can work by giving `EOF` as input from the keyboard as:

> Actually you can send EOF as input. if you are working with Windows hit Ctrl+Z and in Linux Ctrl+D. It is treated as EOF – Pooya

But, as notified by William Pursell, that would be a workaround rather than a valid input:

> Pooya, no, you can't "send EOF". You can close the input stream, which will cause getchar to return EOF. ctrl-D just closes the input stream. Perhaps this is semantics, but "send EOF" implies a sentinel character, which does not exist. – William Pursell

But, to avoid the complication, you will have to use some **sentinel** value to stop the `while` loop, I have used **'!'** here but you can use any suitable character:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
 int blarp, space;
 space = 0;
 
 printf("give me input\n");

 while((blarp = getchar()) != '!')
 {
  if(blarp == ' ')
  {
   space++;
  }
 }
 printf("there are %d spaces\n", space);
}
```

You will have to enter **'!'**, the **sentinel** value, at the end of your input to stop the `while` loop.

Here is the snapshot of my output:

[image]

Comment: you can send EOF from keyboard

Comment: @Pooya Right, I did not know that thanks for informing. I will add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As OP wants to operate on a *line* of data "...to return one line of text  ...", detect an end-of-line `'\n'` as well as EOF.

```
while((blarp = getchar()) != EOF)
while((blarp = getchar()) != EOF && blarp != '\n')
```